# Dancer Quickstart Instructions Not Working

Tags: perl, dancer

I am trying to follow the quick start instructions for Dancer, http://perldancer.org/quickstart.

The first command ...

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo Dancer
```

... worked fine as far as I can tell, but the second command fails like so:

```
$ dancer -a MyWeb::App
bash: dancer: command not found
```

So I figured I look to see where `dancer` got installed and I find this:

```
$ sudo find / -name dancer
/home/red/.cpanm/work/1404922778.2704/Dancer-1.3124/script/dancer
```

I suspect that in install failed somewhere.  Can anyone out there help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to install some rpm's:

```
sudo yum install perl-CPAN
sudo yum install perl-LWP
sudo yum install perl-libwww-perl
sudo yum install perl-Time-HiRes
```

then re-run the `curl` command.